# Unexpected exit conditions on evaluation

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I have a problem with this code number 1, when I send an odd like 3 number, it does not repeat the code in do but the code number 2 it works well.

##### 1

```
int Num = 0;
do
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter The Number ");
} while (Num % 2 == 1 || !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Num));
          
Console.WriteLine(Num);
```

##### 2

```
int Num = 0;
do
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter The Number ");
} while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Num) || Num % 2 ==1 );
          
Console.WriteLine(Num);
```

I think he was repeating the code again that founded in do

Comment: When you use the `||` operator it will do ["boolean short circuiting"](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/) - if the expression on the left of the `||` is true then the expression on the right will *not* be executed.

Comment: This means that in the first loop, once the user enters an odd number the `while` expression will never execute the `int.TryParse()` because `Num % 2 == 1` is true.

Comment: if the first loop is true  The code in do supposed returned , but unfortunately that did not happen

Answer (score 0):

`0 % 2 == 1` - false

`int.TryParse("3")` = true

`!int.TryParse("3")` = false

You have (false || false) - while loop condition should be true to continue working.

For second code, you set the Num first, so `3 % 2 == 1` - true